# Process value in Hashmap based on another value in same Hashmap

Tags: rust

I have a `HashMap` acting as a lookup table in my code, mapping IDs <-> Data.

I need to lookup some data (let's call it Data A) based on my ID, then read the contents. Based on entries in the content, I would then need to lookup another value in the same lookup table, read those data, and do some calculations, updating my original data A.

Here is a minimal working example:

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=af9bb2750fdbdb374cb3569fa64e58e2)

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct MyData {
    id: i32,
    result: i32,
    complex_data: Vec<i32>
}

impl MyData {
    fn new(id: i32) -> Self {
        MyData {
            id,
            result: 0,
            complex_data: Vec::new()
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut lookup_table = HashMap::new();

    // init data
    lookup_table.insert(1, MyData::new(1));
    lookup_table.insert(2, MyData::new(2));
    lookup_table.insert(3, MyData::new(3));
    lookup_table.insert(4, MyData::new(4));

    // process data based on an ID. In this example, hard coded as "1"
    if let Some(data) = lookup_table.get_mut(&1) {
        // process each entry
        for c in data.complex_data.iter() {
            // lookup some more values based the entry
            if let Some(lookup_data) = lookup_table.get(c) {
                                               //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - cannot borrow `lookup_table` as immutable
                // do some calculation and store result
                data.result = lookup_data.result + 42;      // random calculation as an example
            }
        }
    }

    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

The error occurs because it seems I'm borrowing `lookup_table` twice. From what I understand, the compiler is worried that my second lookup also looks up the ID = 1, which will mean I have an mutable reference of DataID = 1, and an immutable reference of DataID = 1 at the same time.

I am fine with this, however, since my second read is immutable, and also this whole thing is single-threaded, so I'm not worried about any race conditions.

How can I restructure my code to make the Rust compiler happy whilst achieving my functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can work around the issue by doing all the reads with an immutable borrow at the first part of the if statement, saving the calculation results into a temporary vector, and doing all the writes with a mutable borrow at the second part. See the code below.

```
// process data based on an ID. In this example, hard coded as "1"
if let Some(data) = lookup_table.get(&1) {
    let mut results = Vec::new();
    // process each entry
    for c in data.complex_data.iter() {
        // lookup some more values based the entry
        if let Some(lookup_data) = lookup_table.get(c) {                                             
            // do some calculation and store result
            results.push(lookup_data.result);
        }
    }
    
    let data = lookup_table.get_mut(&1).unwrap();
    for v in results {
        data.result = v + 42;
    }
}
```

The latter assignment to `data` shadows the previous one and ends the lifetime of the immutable borrow.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c1143d4cb3e72a8c561ae07022a3efd8)

Answer (score 1):

You can use interior mutability pattern on `result` field. This gives you the possibility to make an immutable borrow `&MyData` in the outer loop, and mutate its `result` field in the inner loop. The borrow checker doesn't complain because all checks are done at runtime.

And at runtime, you never have several mutable ref at the same time.

```rust
use std::{cell::RefCell, collections::HashMap};

struct MyData {
    id: i32,
    result: RefCell<i32>,
    complex_data: Vec<i32>,
}

impl MyData {
    fn new(id: i32) -> Self {
        MyData {
            id,
            result: RefCell::new(0),
            complex_data: vec![1, 2, 3, 4],
        }
    }

    fn set_result(&self, result: i32) {
        *self.result.borrow_mut() = result;
    }

    fn get_result(&self) -> i32 {
        self.result.take()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut lookup_table = HashMap::new();

    // init data
    lookup_table.insert(1, MyData::new(1));
    lookup_table.insert(2, MyData::new(2));
    lookup_table.insert(3, MyData::new(3));
    lookup_table.insert(4, MyData::new(4));

    // process data based on an ID. In this example, hard coded as "1"
    if let Some(data) = lookup_table.get(&1) {
        // process each entry
        for c in data.complex_data.iter() {
            // lookup some more values based the entry
            if let Some(lookup_data) = lookup_table.get(c) {
                //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - cannot borrow `lookup_table` as immutable
                // do some calculation and store result
                data.set_result(lookup_data.get_result() + 42);
                // random calculation as an example
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't want to pay the runtime cost, you can use the interior mutability pattern with `Cell` instead of `RefCell`.

Answer (score 1):

Interior mutability is one option, as presented in a previous answer. Collecting the values is another option, as presented in another previous answer. Depending on the nature of your calculation, you might not need any allocation at all, but just store intermediate results in a global variable, and assign it at the end.

For example, this compiles:

```
fn main() {
    let mut lookup_table = HashMap::from([
        (1, MyData::new(1)),
        (2, MyData::new(2)),
        (3, MyData::new(3)),
        (4, MyData::new(4)),
    ]);

    let data_key = 1;
    let mut to_store = None;
    if let Some(data) = lookup_table.get(&data_key) {
        let mut result = data.result;
        for subkey in &data.complex_data {
            if let Some(sub_data) = lookup_table.get(subkey) {
                result += sub_data.result + 42;
            }
        }
        to_store = Some(result);
    }
    if let Some(to_store) = to_store {
        lookup_table.get_mut(&data_key).unwrap().result = to_store;
    }

    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=42a50b93440d7e32f77cc188ec5909c9)